# Hard Fault when printf floats stm32

Tags: printf, stm32

I wrote on stm32cubeIDE 1.11.0 a program that **calculates the fft of a sine wave** (which I always generate via software). I have obviously downloaded the imported DSP libraries into the project.
I should print the frequency and its amplitude on the screen (to see the ideal peak at the frequency of the sine wave) but **the instruction
*printf("frequency %f: %f \n", (float32_t)frequencies_axis[i], output_fft_mag[i]);*
causes Hard Fault interrupt** ... which does not happen if I print integers and/or strings.

The main is empty (it only calls the function in question) and under the main are the initializations done automatically by stm32cubeIDE .. so I am attaching only the code of the function (to simplify things) because the problem in my opinion is either in the code I wrote or in the IDE settings.

This is my first time using printf, so I may have made a stupid mistake in the code. I kindly ask you to check it out. Thank you in advance.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
//All global variables
#define FFT_BUFFER_SIZE 256
#define SAMPLING_RATE 16000
arm_rfft_fast_instance_f32 fftHandler;
float32_t input_fft[FFT_BUFFER_SIZE];
float32_t output_fft[FFT_BUFFER_SIZE];
float32_t output_fft_mag[FFT_BUFFER_SIZE / 2];
float32_t sine_val[100];
float32_t frequencies_axis[FFT_BUFFER_SIZE / 2];


void get_sineval_FFT2() {
//int i = 0;
int frequency = 500;

//generate sinusoidal signal (this is what you receive from outside in the ADC pin, for example)
HAL_Delay(100);
for (int i = 0; i < FFT_BUFFER_SIZE; i++) {
    sine_val[i] = arm_sin_f32(2*PI*frequency*i/SAMPLING_RATE);
    //"sine_val" contains only one frequency (500Hz), so "output_fft" must contain all 0 except a spike at 500Hz
}

arm_rfft_fast_f32(&fftHandler, sine_val, output_fft, 0); //"output_fft" contiene: frequency values and phase information (è formato da complex numbers: in posizione pari ci sono i numeri reali e in posizione dispari c'è la complex immaginary part del numero )                                           k
arm_cmplx_mag_f32(output_fft, output_fft_mag, FFT_BUFFER_SIZE/2); //estraggo magnitude perchè ci interessa quella .. non ci interessa la fase! Estrai da "output_fft" la magnitude che è, per forza, metà fft (cioè FFT_BUFFER_SIZE/2)


for (int i = 0; i < FFT_BUFFER_SIZE / 2; i++) {
    frequencies_axis[i] = ((i * SAMPLING_RATE) / FFT_BUFFER_SIZE);
    //printf("frequencies_axis = %d \n", frequencies_axis[i]);
    printf("frequency %f: %f \n", (float32_t)frequencies_axis[i], output_fft_mag[i]);
    HAL_Delay(50);

    //sprintf(frequencies_axis_str[i], "%f", frequencies_axis[i]); //Ora "frequencies_axis_str" contains "frequencies_axis" as characters
    //printf("frequencies_axis %c : %f \n", frequencies_axis_str[i], output_fft_mag[i]);
    //HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart1, (uint16_t*)(frequencies_axis_str[i]), FFT_BUFFER_SIZE / 2, HAL_MAX_DELAY);
}

}
```

Comment: sprintf() fails too?

Comment: The `%f` format specifier normally indicates that a `double` is expected. Does casting your value to a double help?

Comment: Also note that `printf("%f...)" [uses malloc() internally](https://nadler.com/embedded/newlibAndFreeRTOS.html). Make sure your stack and heap are "big enough".

Comment: @pmacfarlane I declared "double" the two variables used inside printf and now it works. I hadn't really thought about it. It is still not clear to me why it works now ... was it a memory issue? What has changed between float and double? (beyond format and precision)

Comment: @KaleM Using the wrong type of parameter for a `printf()` conversion leads to Undefined Behaviour. So pretty much anything could happen. I'm not sure what the actual practical reason is for it causing a hard fault though. Maybe a stack underflow.

Comment: @pmacfarlane _[...] leads to Undefined Behaviour_ no it doesn't; the arguments are converted according to the format specifier, i.e. the _float_ argument is converted to _double_, which is a perfectly legal conversion. What I with no further insight to the problem guess is, that the FPU is not enabled (similarly to [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/687533/possible-fpu-error) ), the above conversion uses FPU instructions, and the ARM functions for whatever reason don't use them.

Comment: I guess you acess the arrays outside bounds of fpu not exabled in steartup files

Comment: I'm still not sure why, but I think I solved it by setting the first element read by the ADC to zero and using doubles